# How to search for a text from column1 in column2 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select, expression

I have street names in a column  (column1) as well as in another one (column2). I would like to write a selection expression to find out if there are similar street names (or parts of the names) between column1 and column2.

I tried the following expression, but nothing happened. Basically, this is what I would like to achieve but it seems like this is not the right solution:

`"column1" like '%"column2"%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"column1" LIKE concat('%',"column2",'%') OR "column2" LIKE concat('%',"column1",'%')
```

That will search in both ways.